# R Adjacency Matrix - Get proportion of ties with certain attribute value

Tags: r, matrix, adjacency-matrix

I have a adjacency matrix depicting friendships. Further I have attribute values for the actors of the matrix stored in vectors (e.g. gender). My aim is to get the percentage of male and female friends for males and females respectively.

```
e.g. matrix A
 Actor 1   2    3
[1,]  0    1    1
[2,]  0    0    1
[3,]  1    1    0
.
gender <- c("male", "female", "male")
```

In this example above the result should look something like this:

```
        male  female
male    50%    50%
female  100%   0%
```

I`m thankful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
# define matrix
m <- matrix(c(0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0),nrow = 3, ncol = 3)

# define gender vector
gender <- c("male", "female", "male")

# find: male-male friendships
mm <- subset.matrix(m, subset = gender == "male", select = gender == "male")
sum(mm)/(dim(mm)[1]*dim(mm)[2])
```

Which gives you the 1,1 element of your output matrix

But i'm a litte confused. Shouldn't you matrix be symmetric, such that percent_males_friends_with_females are equal to percent_females_that_are_friends_with_males ?